# No Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have moved my file from localhost to another host.

When I moved my files I had a problem and I used jquery, ajax, and php.

This is the error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/site1/admin/pagination.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://moviesnow.tecpt.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

jquery code in artical.php:

```
pagination();
function pagination(page){
    $.ajax({
        url:"pagination.php",
        method:"GET",
        data:{page:page},
        success:function(data){
            $('#pagination').html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information, please?

Comment: yeah i edited the artical

Comment: I have made several clarifications in my edit of your question.  You are free to re-edit your question to add more relevant information.